# On the Paleto Score, does the death of the gunman changes gameplay of the mission?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

According to the [Fandom page](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/The_Paleto_Score):

> If an unskilled gunman is chosen, he will be crushed by a police car [once they enter the construction yard]

and

> If the gunman is alive, he'll help by distracting and holding back some of the soldiers outside [of the chicken factory]

Does this changes the playthrough of the mission? (like enemy count and the speed that takes for the train to appear)

So far, I have not seen changes between a good gunman ([Packie](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Patrick_McReary)) and a bad gunman ([Daryl](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Daryl_Johns)).

Answer (score 3):

It makes the mission slightly harder (as you'll have one ally less shooting back at the police) and results in a loss of profit (since the money the gunman carries is lost).